# Group by ignore column in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I hope and everyone is well, I have a weekly count, where I have the id_txn, payment method and the way to pay, but I have an exception and that is that when I have a specific scenario.

Fields:

```
| id_txn | way_pay | payment_meth |
| 123435 | gateway | transfer    
| 433564 | on-site | cash
| 354641 | gateway | cash 
| 124553 | paypal  | transfer
```

But I want to ignore the `way_pay` column in the query result. My query:

```
select 
  case when way_pay in ('gateway','paypal') and payment_meth = 'transfer' then 'paypal' else way_pay 
  end way_pay,payment_meth,
   count(distinct id_txn) as ttl_pays
from 
pays
where
    init_date between trunc(sysdate-7) and trunc(sysdate)
group by
    case when way_pay in ('gateway','paypal') and payment_meth = 'transfer' then 'paypal' else way_pay end,
    payment_meth
```

Results:

```
 way_pay | payment_meth | ttl_pays

 gateway | transfer     | 23435
```

I want all transactions without filter, but without `payment_meth` column:

```
 way_pay | ttl_pays

 gateway |  123214
 on-site |  32674
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify. Also what is the problem with your query?

Comment: thansk bro, edited! @forpas

Comment: If you want to *ignore* way_pay, why is it in the expected results? Or do you mean something else by *ignore*? Also when I asked for expected results I meant readable results in a tabular format but you posted 1 single row of data that can't be related to your sample data.

Comment: edited! @forpas

Comment: Please provide sample input data as well